# Extending an existing UI for QMainWindow by additional menus with Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a basic image viewing application using Qt and C++, i.e. I have a class

```
ImageViewApp : public QMainWindow, private Ui::ImageViewer {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ImageViewApp ( const char * InputFilename = NULL ) {
    setupUi ( this );
  }
};
```

with a .ui file created with Qt Designer, that generates a header file defining

```
class Ui_ImageViewer {
public:
  void setupUi(QMainWindow *ImageViewer) { … }
};

namespace Ui {
  class ImageViewer: public Ui_ImageViewer {};
} // namespace Ui
```

Now I would like to write another application `ImageRegistrationApp`, where I extend the `QMenuBar` of `ImageViewApp` by additional `QMenu`s containing `QAction`s for a certain purpose, say image registration. Additionally, I would like to change some other things, such as the `windowTitle` and add `QAction`s to existing `QMenu`s of `ImageViewApp`.

I am looking for a way where I don't need to touch or copy the the .ui file of `ImageViewApp`. I would like to do something like inheritance, where changes to the UI of `ImageViewApp` affect the UI of `ImageRegistrationApp`. Also I would like to be able to create and edit the additional `QMenu`s and `QAction`s for `ImageRegistrationApp` via Qt Designer.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**:

I tried changing the title of ImageRegistrationApp and adding a `QAction` to an existing `QMenu` in `ImageViewApp` through inheritance within C++ as follows:

```
ImageRegistrationApp : public ImageViewApp {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  QAction *actionTest;

ImageRegistrationApp ( const char * InputFilename = NULL )
  : ImageViewApp ( InputFilename ) {
  this->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("ImageViewer", "ImReg", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
  actionTest = new QAction(this);
  actionTest->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionTest"));
  actionTest->setText(QApplication::translate("ImageViewer", "Test", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
  this->menuTools->addAction(actionTest);
}

protected slots:
  void on_actionTest_triggered() {
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Test", "Hello world!" );
  }
};
```

I also changed the inheritance in `ImageViewApp` to `protected Ui::ImageViewer` in order to be able to access the Ui elements.

The title of my `ImageRegistrationApp` changes as intended and also the `QAction` `Test` shows up in the menu `Tools`, but when I click it, nothing happens though I expect it to display the `QMessageBox` as defined in the `slot` `on_actionTest_triggered`.

Is there anything else I have to do, to connect the `QAction` with the slot?
I tried `QObject::connect(actionTest, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionTest));` but this did not change anything.

Comment: It is possible, but much simpler to do it via C++ code.

Comment: What would the possibility to do it with Qt Designer look like?

Comment: Yes. If you have complex menu, you should write a "menu manager" that will implement all your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the slot not being executed when the `QAction` `actionTest` was triggered, was a misspelling. I had also tried `QObject::connect(actionTest, SIGNAL(on_triggered()), this, SLOT(on_actionTest_triggered));` before, but there were the `()` missing at the end.

Adding the following line at the end of the constructor of `ImageRegistrationApp` solved the problem:

```
QObject::connect(actionTest, SIGNAL(on_triggered()), this, SLOT(on_actionTest_triggered()));
```

Instantiating `ImageRegistrationApp` now instantiates the entire GUI of `ImageViewApp` and adds the additionally defined `QAction`s to the respective `QMenu`s. This method should be capable of everything I asked for in the question, except for designing additional `QMenu`s with Qt Designer. Instead, everything has to be coded in C++ source.